# Is there a way to auto format all changed files in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, code-formatting, autoformatting

I don't want to auto-format the whole project and get blame in files I have not edited in this PR.
Can I apply linting on only the modified files without manually having to find and select them?

If not, is there a good way to manually find and select all altered files in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way.
Just select any file -> format -> scope -> All changed files

[image]